# Symfony YAML format conversion

Tags: php, symfony, format, yaml, config

I have some service definition that looks like this:

```
MyService:
    class: Some\Class\Here
    factory:
        - SomeFactoryHere
        - method
    calls:
        - [add, ["@=service('AnotherService1').create(service('AnotherService2'), service('AnotherService3'), service('AnotherService3'))"]]
```

IMHO, this can be more readable if converted to something like this:

```
MyService:
    class: Some\Class\Here
    factory:
        - SomeFactoryHere
        - method
    calls:
        -
          add,
          "@=service('AnotherService1').create(
              service('AnotherService2'),
              service('AnotherService3'),
              service('AnotherService3')
          )"
```

But, this is not valid YAML (Symfony parser fails), and my question is how this config can be converted to something like above?

**UPD#1**

Look at [Symfony YAML format conversion: "calls" with string params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38912122/symfony-yaml-format-conversion-calls-with-string-params) - important nuances are there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to break up your string

```
"@=service('AnotherService1').create(service('AnotherService2'), service('AnotherService3'), service('AnotherService3'))"
```

is by using a stripped [folded block scalar](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2796251). The limitation for this is that you cannot escape any special characters with backslashes, but those are not in your example (the reason you need `""` around your scalar is because it starts with an `@` which is a reserved character).

Then you also have to correctly re-represent the structure that you have, as @flyx already indicated: the value for `calls` is a sequence, the first element of which is a list of the scalar `add` and sequence consisting of the aforementioned long scalar that you want to break up for readability:

```
import yaml

yaml_str = """\
MyService:
    class: Some\Class\Here
    factory:
        - SomeFactoryHere
        - method
    calls:
        - - add
          - - >-
              @=service('AnotherService1').create(
              service('AnotherService2'),
              service('AnotherService3'),
              service('AnotherService3'))
"""

data = yaml.safe_load(yaml_str)
print(data)
```

gives:

```
"@=service('AnotherService1').create( service('AnotherService2'), service('AnotherService3'), service('AnotherService3'))"
```

Please note that this gives an extra space between `.create(` and `service(`.

The YAML parser that Symphony uses seems not to be able to parse the above (although it is correct). You can alternatively try:

```
MyService:
    class: Some\Class\Here
    factory:
        - SomeFactoryHere
        - method
    calls:
        - 
          - add
          - 
            - >-
              @=service('AnotherService1').create(
              service('AnotherService2'),
              service('AnotherService3'),
              service('AnotherService3'))
```

Comment: My answer does not add any whitespace to the resulting string. How do you get that idea?

Comment: @flyx Load it and then dump it, just like I did.

Comment: If the YAML implementation of your choice adds spaces to the scalar in my answer, it is not a correct YAML implementation. The spec says that [All leading and trailing white space characters are excluded from the content.](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2787839).

Comment: @flyx You might be right, I'll have to look into that why PyYAML does that.

Comment: I see you use PyYAML. Python supports backslash escapes inside long string literals, so make sure you *escape the backslashes in the YAML*  to get proper output.

Comment: @flyx I just realise that I should use \\ in the yaml_str, sorry for that, and thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Sorry for being annoying, but there still is an error in your answer. Your YAML actually adds a newline to the end of the string. To avoid that, start the folded scalar with `>-` instead of just `>`.

Comment: That is not annoying. I added that to my example code after I copy-and-pasted the code in, but before I copy-pasted the example. I should get some more coffee before answering on SO in the morning.

Comment: In symfony, this fails with: Unable to parse at line 616 (near "  - - >-").

Comment: The parser that symphony uses is non-compliant. You can test this at http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/ or http://www.yamllint.com/. I'll update the example with something symphony with this defect might be able to understand.

Comment: Can you update your post with suggestion how to format almost same YAML, but with string params? Current method not working for this: "calls: - [create, ["%param1%", "%param2%"]]"

Comment: Compiled container loks like " $instance->create('param1, param2');" - two params are concatenated to one string, but create() method expects two args.

Comment: @alex I'm not sure why it doesn't, but I have difficulty to visualise what you did. You probably missed some '-'. Can make a new question (refer to this one), in that first show what works, and then adding what makes it break?

Comment: @Anthon, ok, Iam post a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38912122/symfony-yaml-format-conversion-calls-with-string-params

Comment: Also, please look and UPD#1 in the new question, there is a part related to this question.

Comment: @alex I answered, you were missing a `-` in the rewrite

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote is valid YAML. If the Symfony parser fails, it has a bug. But anyway, the second YAML does not represent the same structure as the first YAML.

In the first YAML, `calls` is a sequence. The first sequence item of `calls` is also a sequence, which contains the scalar `add` and yet another sequence. In the second YAML, `calls` is also a sequence, but the item it contains is a scalar which contains everything from `add,` to `)"`. The comma is content here, because you did not start a flow sequence (with `[`). Here is block-style YAML which is equivalent to the first YAML:

```
MyService:
    class: Some\Class\Here
    factory:
        - SomeFactoryHere
        - method
    calls:
        - - add
          - - "@=service('AnotherService1').create(\
                 service('AnotherService2'),
                 service('AnotherService3'),
                 service('AnotherService3')\
              )"
```

The backslashes at the end of the string's lines cause no whitespace to be inserted. By default, YAML inserts one space character for each newline in a double-quoted string it encounters. This YAML scalar yield exactly the same string as your first YAML contains.

`- -` is compact style, which starts two nested sequence items at once. So now, `calls` is a sequence again with a sequence as first item. that nested sequence contains a scalar `add` as first item, and another sequence as second item. And that sequence contains the double-quoted scalar.

Comment: If you insert a space between the commas and backslashes then the quoted scalar will get two spaces, just like in the example (in the middle two lines)

Comment: Ah yes, I overlooked those. Updated the answer to not include backslashes where spaces are wanted - which is simpler than adding a space before the backslash.

Comment: In Symfony, this fails with: Unable to parse at line 619 (near "  - - "@=service('AnotherService1').create(\").